# Retrieve the name of the last value as a character vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to automate the naming of a ggplot output saved using `ggsave()`

When I create the following plot I am able to retrieve the name of the plot using a combination of the deparse and substitute functions if I state the plot name explicitly

```
# make the plot
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)   
my_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+geom_point()

# generate the file name
filename <- paste0(deparse(substitute(my_plot)), ".jpg")
filename
```

However, I am trying to pass the plot name to the substitute function directly using without having to state it twice using `.Last.value`. This generates the incorrect result.

```
my_plot_name <- deparse(substitute(.Last.value))
my_plot_name 

## [1] ".Last.value"
```

How can I access the name of the last ggplot object (or any other object) to be saved without stating the name explicitly?

EDIT: To be specific, my desired output based on the above example and some pseudo code would look like this:

```
filename <- paste0(deparse(substitute(.Last.value)), ".jpg")
filename
    
## [1] "my_plot.jpg"
```

Comment: I struggle seeing the conceptual value in this. If you want to "automate" this, why not decide for a fixed name for your plots, like you do above with `my_plot <- ...`. This way, you'll always know the name of the last plot. If this is supposed to be in a loop where you, IDK, create 30 plots, just decide for an equally unique plot name, e.g. by pasting together "my_plot" with the index of the loop, e.g. "my_plot_1" etc.

Comment: So long story short, can you explain in a bit more detail the goal you are trying to achieve and why you think you need to go with .Last.value? Usually, there's at least one alternative in R to achieve things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it directly from the filename you're creating:

```
my_plot_name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)
my_plot_name

## [1] "my_plot"
```

Updated after edits:

`.Last.value` will only store the value, not the name of the variable that the value is being assigned into.  First idea I'd have otherwise would be to check the names of variables in the environment to find which is equal to `.Last.value`.  It seems to work in this simple case of your example:

```
my_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+geom_point()
filename <- paste0(Filter(function(i) identical(get(i), .Last.value), ls()), ".jpg")
filename
## [1] "my_plot.jpg"
```

Comment: I think I have not been very clear - I am trying to name the file based on the output of .Last.value. I will update the question to be more clear

Comment: I've updated it given your clarification

Comment: Great, that did the job perfectly. Thanks!